# Edition supported for creating a system database in managed Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying an ARM template in which I need to create a system database. However during the deployment I always get error "The system is not a valid edition..."

```
      "location": "westus",
      "properties": {
        "edition": "System",
        "status": "Online",
        "serviceLevelObjective": "System2",
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": "32200054720",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "System2",
        "defaultSecondaryLocation": "East US",
        "containmentState": 2
      },
```

Is there any reference/article pointing to list of allowed values for each edition and service objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create system databases in SQL Azure.  There is already a database called system that the service provisions for you.  This is why your request fails.

Comment: So it is impossible if I try to create a system database which the params above?

Comment: you can't create any databases using the system reservation sizes, correct.  You can't create system databases period - those are owned by the system (and are not billed to you)